# Mixed Content (laravel)

Tags: laravel-5

I get the following error (on every page)

app.js:703 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sitename.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://sitename.com/index.php/getMessages'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

The site is build with Laravel.
Is there anybody who knows how to fix this error?

Comment: You need to set all your website pages to use https

Answer (score 47):

In my case it's because I wasn't aware that the `asset()` function didn't handle https automatically (as pointed out by [frankfurt-laravel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252531/4075723)).

To get around this, since I don't use SSL in dev, I set `ASSET_URL` in the .env to the https url:

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

This overrides the `asset()` function to use the https url, without having to modify the function at all. See [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-asset) for more context.

Comment: Works as of Laravel 7.x too. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed me.  Strangely out of 6 identical L7 deployments, only 1 site needed this.

Comment: dude, that's great. thanks a lot.

Comment: It fixed my app. thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Laravel 9. Actually I have managed to work with https in local mode and nothing related to mixed content was caused. However, turning to production, this problem shows up. Then I don't get it.

Comment: works for laravel 10 as well. thanks

Answer (score 19):

If you are moving the website from HTTP to HTTPS, and it's was working perfectly on HTTP, and if you have added the new URL with https in config/app.php and also in the .env file then you may need to add the below snippet in your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file's boot function and do not forget to add "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;" at the top of the file to fix this error.
[Please check attached for better sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7quz.png)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

public function boot()
{
       URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem few days ago. Do you use Cloudflare? Change flexible SSL to Full.

Comment: Saved lot of time. :)

Comment: Thank you for saving me another hour!

Comment: This fixed it for me, but don't forget to install a certificate on your origin server as well.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to use the method argument `$secure` Laravel (5.6 has it definitely) provides:

When you use **asset loading**, e.g.

```
 <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can lookup the definition for `asset()`, if you have some kind of advanced IDE. If not, please check this file `helpers.php`.

However, the documentation says

```
/**
 * Generate an asset path for the application.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
```

So you just need to pass `true` as the **second argument**, and then the resource is loaded in a secure way. For above examples it would be

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js',true) }}" defer></script>
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css', true) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please note, this will cause conflict if you use `php artisan serve`, as artisan is not capable to serve via HTTPS protocol. Thus you need HTTPS setup e.g. with [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#securing-sites) on MacOS or [Homestead](https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-setup-https-with-laravel-homestead-ad7915470fa8) on Windows. Follow the links for setup details.

Hope this helps, please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thank you, this problem was driving me nuts!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks Frankfurter! :P

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to remove trailing slashes from XMLHttpRequest endpoint URL.

Comment: I do not believe this is the solution for the person asking the question, but it solved my problem when I saw this answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel Octane, I figured the fix by looking at `octane.php` config file.

Set your env to let octane inform upstream framework to use HTTPS.

```
OCTANE_HTTPS=true
```

Fixed the issues I was having with mixed-content and email verification signature failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file set your url to https `APP_URL=https://sitename.com` and in your config/app.php set url to `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'APP_URL=https://sitename.com'),` that should solve your problem

Comment: The Env file I changed on deploying the site, the latter I changed just now but didn't seem to have any effect...(still the same error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 8 and Livewire 2. I created the app on Digital Ocean and to fix those issues, I had to do it like this:

```
<!-- Tailwind CSS -->
<link href="{{ secure_asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    
<!-- Alpine -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ secure_asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@livewireStyles
```

I had to used secure_asset instead. That's on the Laravel Documentation.

I also had to change all "route" references for secure_url like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
<form method="POST" action="{{ secure_url('/logout') }}">
```

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score -4):

You opened the page 'https://sitename.com/' . But the javascript of this page sent an http request, not https.

You should change your javascript code to send https request.

There are two ways to send https request:

1. Put the protocol together with path.

   $.get('http://sitename.com/index.php/getMessages')
2. Ignore the protocol, but put '//' before the path

   $.get('//sitename.com/index.php/getMessages')

Comment: How/where would I implement this in a Laravel project (I am a newbie when it comes to laravel and JavaScript)