# Mixed Content: The page at 'domain' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ssl, vuejs3, inertiajs

I've been trying to resolve an error that happens only in production. When I try to `create` a new database entry, following errors are thrown:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://strong-moebel.art/admin/gallerie/neu' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://strong-moebel.art/admin/gallerie'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at wh (main.750d1ea1.js:4:96980)
    at s.onerror (main.750d1ea1.js:5:1837)
```

everything else works, including the `edit` method of the entries. I'm using a `resource controller`. `create` method uses inertia's `form.post` and `edit` method uses its `form.put` (if that's relevant).

I've been trying to debug this with the solutions provided in:

1. [Mixed content issue- Content must be served as HTTPS](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mixed-content-issue-content-must-be-served-as-https)
2. [Mixed Content (laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018712/mixed-content-laravel)

basically people are saying to add:

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

to the `boot()` method of your `AppServiceProvider.php`. I've done so but the error still occurs. I'm wondering if this is an inertia issue.

On the server, I've tried:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_URL=https://localhost
APP_URL=
APP_URL=http://strong-moebel.art
APP_URL=https://strong-moebel.art
```

but nothing seems to solve the issue. My webhost is cloudways and I'm using their `Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate`. I've also tried to remove the certificate and see what happens but even then the exact same error occurs. I'm not very educated on `SSL` and was wondering if someone could help me resolve the issue or point to something I could investigate.

I'm using `vite` to build production built.

## **Update**:

The component from which the request is sent via `form.post`:

```
<template layout="backend/cms-layout">
  <div id="cms-gallery-create" class="cms-gallery-create">
    <form @submit.prevent="storeRecord" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="title-btn-bar">
        <h1>Erstelle eine Kreation:</h1>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Kreation speichern">
      </div>
      <p>Titel:</p>
      <input class="textfield-closed title-field" v-model="form.title">
      <p>Titelbild:</p>
      <cms-img-upload v-model:image="form.image"/>
      <p>Hauptteil:</p>
      <cms-custom-editor v-model="form.body"/>
    </form>
    <div v-if="errors.target" class="error">{{ errors.target }}</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import CmsImgUpload from '../../components/backend/cms-img-upload.vue'
import CmsCustomEditor from '../../components/backend/cms-custom-editor.vue'
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

const props = defineProps({
    errors: Object
})

const form = useForm({
    title: '',
    body: '',
    image: '',
})

const storeRecord = () => {
    form.post('/admin/gallerie/')
}

</script>
```

it is then routed by `inertia` to the backend -> **`web.php`**:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() {
    Route::inertia('/admin/dashboard', 'backend/cms-dashboard');

    Route::post('/admin/gallerie/move', [GalleryController::class, 'moveRow']);
    Route::resource('/admin/gallerie', GalleryController::class);

    Route::post('/admin/verkauf/move', [ShopController::class, 'moveRow']);
    Route::resource('/admin/verkauf', ShopController::class);

    Route::post('/admin/logout', [LoginController::class, 'destroy']);
});
```

and sent to a `resource controller` via:

```
Route::resource('/admin/gallerie', GalleryController::class);
```

Inside the controller, this method is called to store the request data inside the database:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->image) {
        $image_path = Custom::storeBase64Image($this->STORAGE_PATH, $request);
    } else {
        $image_path = null;
    }

    Gallery::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'image_path' => $image_path
    ]);

    return redirect($this->BASE_URL);
}
```

The problem seems to happen in the frontend, since there are no `logs` created.

Comment: can you show the code where you make this request? http ://strong-moebel.art/admin/gallerie

Comment: @PaulTsai I've updated my question with the requested information

Comment: Have you tried this one: form.post('/admin/gallerie') without the ending slash

Comment: @PaulTsai My god, I can't believe it. This seems to the problem. All my requests have the trailing `/` and only this one throws the error (only in production). It's working now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulTsai it works now. I had to change:

```
form.post('/admin/gallerie/')
```

to:

```
form.post('/admin/gallerie')
```

**`Edit`**:

I've just experienced exactly the same issue but with the `fetch` api, this time with `paypal`. In production I had to change:

```
fetch('/api/paypal/order/create/', ...
```

to:

```
fetch('/api/paypal/order/create', ...
```

Maybe it helps someone

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this error and tried almost all the suggestions above but nothing worked. I however came across a medium post that suggested adding the following meta tag and it worked for me.

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
</head>
```

So you basically need to add that meta tag in the head tag of your main layout file if you are using Laravel. For more information, read
[this post](https://medium.com/geekculture/mixed-content-the-page-at-xxx-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-yyy-95086e0293f7)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **nginx reverse proxy**, and you can edit the config file, simply add this directive  to force the upgrade to HTTPS

```
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in the `boot` function in `AppServiceProvider`

```
URL::forceRootUrl(Config::get('app.url'));
    if (str_contains(Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 9, edit /app/Helpers/helper.php

```
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://';
```

To

```
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://';
```

Under the myAssetSRC Function.

Kind of dirty but only thing that worked for me.