# Laravel 10 on https redirects to http /home

Tags: php, laravel

I have already serched for answers, like this [Mixed Content (laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018712/mixed-content-laravel) and similar and they did not helped.
I have:

```
APP_URL="https://doma.in"
ASSET_URL="https://doma.in"
APP_USE_HTTPS=true
FORCE_HTTPS=true
SESSION_DOMAIN="doma.in"
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
```

also `AppServiceProvider -> boot -> \URL::forceScheme('https');`

app.blade is having `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

also login form has url https://doma.in/login

and during deploy I do all php artisan clear comands and dump-autoload

Problem: L10 redirects to http://doma.in/home and i can not login.
Do you have some ideas how to make it to redirect to https://doma.in/home  ?

Comment: are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: @lagbox , yes, Devops just told me  we have "x-real-ip"

Comment: @lagbox Added protected $proxies = '*'; and now after login, i see redirect to https : // doma.in/home (302) but after this, I get one more redirect to Login. Seems we solved a half of answer, maybe you have idea what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i couldn't drop this as comment

the redirection is tricky since you have tried most of the know fixes,

the only additional suggestion I think you can check is .httaccess /nginx/apache config

you can redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

an example of this using .httaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

another option is to do this with a middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```